# Flutter- Too few positional arguments: 1 required, 0 given. - upi_payment_qrcode_generator

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, qr-code, flutter-plugin, upi

I am working on flutter project, Where I am using plugin called `upi_payment_qrcode_generator`, version is 1.2.0.  Previously this was working locally, but after migrating my project to git repo, It is giving error as below.

My Code is :

```
final upiDetails = UPIDetails(
    upiID: "xxxxxxx",
    payeeName: "Mr. abc",
    amount: 200.00,
    transactionNote: "Sample",
  );

Center(
      child: UPIPaymentQRCode(
        upiDetails: upiDetails,
        size: AppSizeConstants.SIZE_170,
        upiQRErrorCorrectLevel: UPIQRErrorCorrectLevel.low,
      ),
    )`
```

```
Error: Too few positional arguments: 1 required, 0 given.
      child: QrImage(
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: I have the same kind of issue with a project I didn't touch for a while. Didn't investigate much but QrImage seems to have changed a lot. So, probably, you need to wait for upi_payment_qrcode_generator to be adapted (or do it yourself).

Comment: Apparently, QrImageView is replacing QrImage.